# Google Maps Directions Service - Require 3 different distances

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps directions service as follows:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var start = arrObjLatLngs[0];
var end = arrObjLatLngs[arrObjLatLngs.length - 1];

arrObjWaypoints = [];

// Get waypoints
if (arrObjLatLngs.length > 2) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arrObjLatLngs.length; i++) {

        arrObjWaypoints.push({
            location:arrObjLatLngs[i],
            stopover:true}
        );  

    }

}

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC,
    provideRouteAlternatives: false,
    waypoints: arrObjWaypoints
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        if (boolShowMap) {

            directionsDisplay.setMap(MapObject);
            $('#cp-div-map').dialog('open');
            google.maps.event.trigger(MapObject, 'resize');
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        } else {

            var total_distance = 0;

            // Add up distance of all available legs
            for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {

                total_distance += parseInt(response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value);

            }

            callBack(total_distance);

        }

    }

});
```

Basically, the first bit is okay for getting the distance between `start` and `end`... however, I also need a seperate value to calculate the distance between `base` and `start`and a third distance which is between `base` and `end`.

I have tried this:-

```
var directionsServicePickup = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var base = "52.781048888889, -1.2110222222222546";

var request2 = {
    origin:base,
    destination:start,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC,
    provideRouteAlternatives: false,
    waypoints: arrObjWaypoints
};


directionsServicePickup.route(request2, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var total_pickup_distance = 0;

            // Add up distance of all available legs
            for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {

                total_pickup_distance += parseInt(response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value);

            }

            var km = parseInt(total_pickup_distance) / 1000;

            // Convert KM into Miles
            var pickup_distance = parseInt((km / 8) * 5);

            alert('Pickup='+pickup_distance);

            var runin_pickup = 1200;

            // Send to our checkRuninTariff function
            checkRuninTariff(runin_pickup);

        }

});
```

But this seems to be overridding the first request that I am sending. I'm not too familiar with this API so any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you just need the driving distance, you could use the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) for the second operation.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding what you mean by getting the results from a different lat/long. Just change the origin surely?

Comment: Basically, I am needing the distance for `origin:start,` to `destination:start,`.... but I am needing a seperate distance value for `origin:base` to `destination:start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the distance between places (but not the directions) use the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

It will compute driving distances between multiple locations in a single call.

[Example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix)